# Convert many png's to multi-page tiff

Tags: imagemagick

I've seen various posts around StackOverflow, but basically I want to do something along the lines of:

```
convert *.png new.tiff
```

And the tiff has a page per each png. So I want a single tiff, with many pages. This doesn't work, it only converts the first png found in the list. For what I'm doing, I actually need a multi-page tiff. Supposedly imagemagick does this.

(BTW, version is: 6.8.0-10 2013-03-03 Q16)

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible to do the contrary: convert a multipage tiff into multiple images?

Comment: @hpixel: `convert old.tif new-%04d.png`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally figured it out. It seems you have to build from source to get this feature working correctly. I used all versions from homebrew without any luck. To do this make sure you get rid of any old versions, so do the following:

1. `brew uninstall imagemagick`
2. `brew unlink imagemagick`
3. `brew install imagemagick --build-from-source`
4. It might say that you need to link/unlink, just do `brew unlink imagemagick && brew link imagemagick` and it should work fine.

I'm very surprised this isn't documented more, specifically converting multiple images into a single multi-paged tiff. From here you can then do `convert *.png mynewimg.tiff` (if using globbing) if not you can do `convert first.png second.png third.png mynewimg.tiff`

It seems the only option is to build from source though, so if multi-paged tiffs aren't being generated then do the above.

Comment: Sounds like a Mac issue. I can't speak for the state of things in 2013, but multi-page TIFF generation works fine with the `convert` included in Ubuntu 16.04.