# building tiff stack with wand

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

How can I achieve this with Wand library for python:

```
convert *.png stack_of_multiple_pngs.tiff
```

?

In particular, how can I read every png image, pack them into a [sequence](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3-maintenance/wand/sequence.html#wand.sequence.SingleImage) and then save the image as tiff stack:

```
with Image(filename='*.tiff') as img:
    img.save(filename='stack_of_multiple_pngs.tiff')
```

I understand how to do it for [gifs](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3.8/guide/sequence.html) though, i.e. as described in docs. But what about building a sequence as a list and appending every new image I read as a SingleImage()?

Having trouble figuring it out right now.

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250071/convert-many-pngs-to-multi-page-tiff)

Answer (score 2):

With `wand` you would use `Image.sequence`, not a wildcard filename `*`.

```py
from wand.image import Image
from glob import glob

# Get list of all images filenames to include
image_names = glob('*.tiff')

# Create new Image, and extend sequence
with Image() as img:
    img.sequence.extend( [ Image(filename=f) for f in image_names ] )
    img.save(filename='stack_of_multiple_pngs.tiff')
```

The [sequence_test.py](https://github.com/dahlia/wand/blob/master/tests/sequence_test.py) file under the test directory will have better examples of working with the image sequence.